# How to dispose of and recreate some state

Tags: widget, flutter, lifecycle

Please, consider the below code.

A textController is created during initState. If a button is pressed, another textController is created, inside of setState:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() { runApp(Test()); }

class Test extends StatefulWidget {
  TestState createState() => TestState();
}

class TestState extends State<Test> {
  TextEditingController textController;

  void initState() {
    print("initState");
    super.initState();

    textController = TextEditingController(text: "1st textController");
  }

  void dispose() {
    print("dispose");
    textController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void onPressed() {
    print("onPressed");

    setState(() {
      print("setState");

      // It breaks if this line is uncommented.
      if (textController != null) textController.dispose();

      textController = TextEditingController(text: "2nd textController");
    });
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("build");

    var button = MaterialButton(onPressed: onPressed, child: const Text("Click Me"));
    var textField = TextField(keyboardType: TextInputType.number, controller: textController);

    return MaterialApp(
      home: Material(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
          child: Column(children: [button, textField]),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

It works. However, I've never disposed of the old textController. I can do that inside of setState, before creating the new textController:

```
    setState(() {
      print("setState");
      if (textController != null) textController.dispose();
      textController = TextEditingController(text: "2nd textController");
    });
```

However, then, I get an error:

```
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞══
I/flutter ( 4645): The following assertion was thrown building             
InputDecorator(decoration: InputDecoration(), isFocused:
I/flutter ( 4645): false, isEmpty: false, state:     
_InputDecoratorState#8195a(tickers: tracking 2 tickers)):
I/flutter ( 4645): A TextEditingController was used after being disposed.
I/flutter ( 4645): Once you have called dispose() on a TextEditingController, it can no longer be used.
```

**My questions:**

1) Why am I getting this error? Is the textControlled still being used? Where?

2) How to fix this?

Comment: Why are you creating a new `TextEditingController` instead of reusing the previously created one? You can't explicitly dispose values. If a value isn't referenced anywhere garbage collection takes care of that.

Comment: What do you mean by "I've never disposed of the old textController" anyway? If you execute `textController = TextEditingController(text: "2nd textController");` the reference to the previous `TextEditingController` is removed and replaced by the new one. If the controller isn't referenced anywhere else, it will be disposed. The next time `build()` is executed, the TextField()` will be released and with it the reference to it's `TextEditingController`. I don't think there is anything more to do.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I am creating a new TextEditingController because this is just an example. In the real code I need to substitute a subclass of TextEditingController with another different subclass.

Comment: I see. Is there any reason why you think you need to do something to get rid of the previous instance?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer If I had only one textController, would I actually need to do `void dispose() { textController.dispose(); super.dispose(); }` ? Or is the dispose method only meant to remove listeners eventually attached to the testController?

Comment: It's just for general cleanup. Cancelling listeners makes sense because otherwise they can receive still events until garbage collection finally disposes of them which can cause errors when the widgets are not mounted anymore. "// It breaks if this line is uncommented." How does it break?

Comment: Ok, so it's "general cleanup" which means it's not necessary. I was under the impression it was necessary because I've seen it done everywhere, including in the official documentation, for example: https://flutter.io/docs/cookbook/forms/text-field-changes

Comment: If something that you instantiated has a `dispose` method it's probably a good idea to call it in `dispose`, but I don't think it's strictly necessary in this case.

Comment: Yes, well, the TextEditingController dispose method doesn't seem to be doing anything that would prevent memory leaks anyway. Thanks!

Comment: I guess Flutter is just updating the TextEditingController, which means the old one and the new one both are the same instance and you disposed the TextEditingController already, so you cant use it anymore.

Comment: why you do not use state management instead of flutter state such as provider with read keyword and not watch.

Answer (score 1):

I've got a couple of observations for you that might help, plus, I've prepared a code sample.

First, there is no need to recreate the `TextEditingController`, as usually there's going to be one for each `TextField`, or `TextFormField` (depending on the implementation). You could also declare it as `final` without the need for the use of `initState()`.

Second, remember to dispose of the TextEditingController inside `dispose()` when it is no longer needed. This will ensure we discard any resources used by the object. There is no need to dispose of it while in use. Remember: the controller is not there to notify listeners of the changes inside the text input field.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

// Main method
void main() {
  runApp(App());
}

// I've made a separate App class that returns MaterialApp
class App extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: HomeScreen(),
    );
  }
}

// HomeScreen replaces your Test
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  // TextEditingController could have been declared final here
  // as well, for example:
  //
  //  final _controller = TextEditingController(text: 'default');
  //
  // but take that as a suggestion for future ;)
  TextEditingController _controller;

  // String we'll be changing
  String _mutableTextString = '';

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    // Simple declarations
    _controller = TextEditingController(text: 'default');
    _mutableTextString = _controller.text;
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // Call the dispose() method of the TextEditingController
    // here, and remember to do it before the super call, as
    // per official documentation:
    // https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/TextEditingController-class.html
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        minimum: const EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
              TextField(
                controller: _controller,
                keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
              ),
              MaterialButton(
                child: Text('CLICK ME'),
                onPressed: _handleOnPressed,
              ),
              Text(_mutableTextString),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  // This method handles actions when the button is pressed
  // and updates the UI
  void _handleOnPressed() {
    setState(() {
      _mutableTextString = _controller.text;
    });
  }
}
```

I've got a short demo for you as well, hopefully, it helps!

[image: Demo of the source code above]

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Why am I getting this error? Is the textControlled still being
>    used? Where?

From what I've seen in your implementation, you are creating the `TextController` in a `setState` call. It should be created once in initState and reusing it during the lifetime of your stateful widget. Here is the part where the error occurs:

```
  void onPressed() {
    print("onPressed");

    setState(() {
      print("setState");

      // It breaks if this line is uncommented.
      if (textController != null) textController.dispose();

      textController = TextEditingController(text: "2nd textController");
    });
  }
```

Since the `textController` has a `String` value of "1st textController" that was set here:

```
void initState() {
    print("initState");
    super.initState();

    textController = TextEditingController(text: "1st textController");
  }
```

Every time you call the `onPressed()`, this line:

```
if (textController != null) textController.dispose();
```

checks the value of `textController`. Since it is not `null`, the `textController` was disposed by the `disposed()` method. There is no way that this next line will run successfully:

```
textController = TextEditingController(text: "2nd textController");
```

> 2. How to fix this?

Currently, you have implemented the dispose() inside `onPressed()` method. If you'll check closely the documentation for [dispose()](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/dispose.html) method, it states that:

> Called when this object is removed from the tree permanently.
>
> The framework calls this method when this
> [State](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State-class.html)
> object will never build again. After the framework calls
> [dispose](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/dispose.html),
> the [State](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State-class.html)
> object is considered unmounted and the
> [mounted](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/mounted.html)
> property is false. It is an error to call
> [setState](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/setState.html)
> at this point. This stage of the lifecycle is terminal: there is no
> way to remount a State object that has been disposed.

Re using your code, what I did is implement the `dispose()` in the `dispose()` method as described in the documentation:

```
void dispose() {
    print("dispose");
    // This is the line that breaks when called inside setState() of onPressed() method
    if (textController != null) textController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
```

So your code will look like this way:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(Test());
}

class Test extends StatefulWidget {
  TestState createState() => TestState();
}

class TestState extends State<Test> {
  TextEditingController textController;

  void initState() {
    print("initState");
    super.initState();
    textController = TextEditingController(text: "1st textController");
  }

  void onPressed() {
    print("onPressed");

    setState(() {
      print("setState");
      print(textController);
      // It breaks if this line is uncommented.
      // if (textController != null) textController.dispose();
      textController = TextEditingController(text: "2nd textController");
    });
  }

  void dispose() {
    print("dispose");
    // This is the line that breaks when called inside setState() of onPressed() method
    if (textController != null) textController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("build");

    var button =
        MaterialButton(onPressed: onPressed, child: const Text("Click Me"));
    var textField = TextField(
        keyboardType: TextInputType.number, controller: textController);

    return MaterialApp(
      home: Material(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
          child: Column(children: [button, textField]),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And it's working like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

## To answer why

Here is what's happening:

1. You dispose the `TextEditingController`. It's OK by itself.
2. The app is rebuilt.
3. The `TextField` sees its controller changed.
4. It stops listening to the old controller by calling `removeListener` on it.
5. The controller checks if it is disposed and breaks:

[image]

So the rule is to never dispose controllers until they stop being listened to. And this can only happen after everything is rebuilt with new controllers.

## To answer how to fix

You say that

> In the real code I need to substitute a subclass of TextEditingController with another different subclass.

I see the following options:

1. Ideally, `TextEditingController` (as any `ValueNotifier`) should go hand-in-hand with its widget. So you may have your own stateful widget instead of that `TextField`, create its controller there and dispose it there. When you need to replace the controller, replace the whole widget. This way, Flutter framework takes care of disposal.
2. Make your own super-`ValueNotifier` that aggregates your different subclasses, exposes different `TextEditingController` instances in different states of your screen, and disposes them all in its `dispose()`. Create it once in your `initState()`, dispose it once in `dispose()`.
3. Keep a list of old controllers and dispose them all in your state's `dispose()` method as the last resort. But it makes it all too messy.

`TextEditingController` is something that maintains the value, allows to change it and to know that it is changed. That's it. If you want to replace it while the screen is still shown, it means you are treating it as something else which can bring problems.